# Android - ImageView / ImageButton with image from gallery or camera

Tags: android, image

I know there are many posts like this but mine is a little special.

> Problem Description:

I want a public class that shows a small dialog to select image source, camera or gallery. After choosing, an ImageView will show the image and the image will be saves in app folder. This class will be called from many activities. So, I have this code:

**PhotoActivity.java**

```
package com.app.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PhotoActivity {

    private Context context;

    public PhotoActivity(Context current){
        this.context = current;
    }
    //this will be called from other activities
    public void Change_Photo(final Activity a) {

        List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
        options.add(context.getResources().getString(R.string.camera));
        options.add(context.getResources().getString(R.string.gallery));
        options.add(context.getResources().getString(R.string.cancel));

        //Create sequence of items
        final CharSequence[] Sources = options.toArray(new String[options.size()]);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.select_image_source));
        dialogBuilder.setItems(Sources, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item==0) {//camera
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    a.startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replaced with any action code
                }else if (item == 1) {//gallery
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    a.startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);//one can be replaced with any action code
                }
            }
        });
        //Create alert dialog object via builder
        AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();
        //Show the dialog
        alertDialogObject.show();
    }
}
```

I have add in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Other activites have an ImageView or ImageButton like this:

```
<ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/btn_picture"
      android:layout_width="140dp"
      android:layout_height="140dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
      android:elevation="0dp"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:src="@drawable/camera" />
```

which has a camera image in the beginning but will show the selected image in the end.

What must be done next to show the selected or taken photo in this ImageButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 Uri uri = data.getData();
try {
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
// imageButton where you want to set image
imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch(IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

This is how you can set your selected / captured image on ImageButton.

Hope this will help.

Comment: A better option than `getBitmap()` and `setImageBitmap()` would be to use [an image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as Picasso. The code shown in the answer loads the image on the main application thread, which will freeze the UI.

Comment: This did the job. A small question. When I take a new photo, ImageButton shows it rotated left 90 degrees. Why?

Comment: This depends on size of photo, Take small picture and try again